# Creating a texture (image) from uint8Array

Tags: axios, textures, arraybuffer, uint8array

I'm trying to go from a JPG on the web to create a texture with uint8Array.

I need uint8Array as it's an API that only accepts that format.

To get the data I request the data with `responseType: "arraybuffer"`.

```js
      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: imageString,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          const uintPic = new Uint8Array(response.data)
     }
```

Here comes the first question: How I'm supposed to get the width and height of the image? I looked it up from the example to move forward, but couldn't find it out.

Then I'm setting up the pixels like this:

```js
    var width = 200;
    var height = 113;
    var channels = 4; // RGBA
    var pixels = width * height * channels;

    // I create a new Uint8Array with space to hold the Alpha channel
    var newData = new Uint8Array(pixels); 

    var s = 0;
    var d = 0;
    while (d < pixels) {
       newData[d++] = uintPic[s++];
       newData[d++] = uintPic[s];
       newData[d++] = uintPic[s];
       newData[d++] = 255;
       s++
    }
```

The second issue is that there's not enough information coming from `uintPic` which has a length of 2.784 when it should have at least 67.800 (width * height * 3channels).

I tested the data coming from the axios response using Blob in the browser and the data seems to be enough to create an image though:

```js
// First the Blob:
const blob = new Blob(
    [new Uint8Array([uintPic])],
    { type: 'image/jpg' }
);

// Now the image.
const img = new Image();
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/) as a library worked so far:

```js
      Jimp.read(url, function (err, image) {
          console.log(" ~ image.bitmap.data:", image.bitmap.data)
      });
```